# How to change nautilus title bar background color?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, colors

I want the titlebar background color of Nautilus (when active window) to be significantly different from the title bars of background windows. By default, the background color is too similar to background windows.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and default Yaru theme.

[image: This is what I want to change]

I tried modifying the file /home/ubuntu/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css like below. The changes below are successful at changing the titlebar background color for most windows (Firefox, Thunderbird and more) but have no affect on Nautilus, System Monitor or Settings:

```
/* use blue when ACTIVE */
.nautilus-window .titlebar, .titlebar {
    background: #1856dd;
    color:white; 
}
/* use dark grey when NOT active */
.nautilus-window .titlebar:backdrop, .titlebar:backdrop  {
    background: #3E3D3A;
    color:#807D78;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nautilus doesn't use GTK ; and with it the GTK title bar. Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276951), you may find a workaround for your specific demand :-)